# maven build (with nar-packaging-type) fails in Mac (El Caption) with suffix or operands invalid for `movq'

Tags: maven, gcc, osx-elcapitan

I recently upgraded my Mac os X version to El Caption. I also fixed the problem with "Command Line Tools" (via xcode-select --install).

I currently have the following gcc version

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0/5.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Configured with: ../gcc-5.3.0/configure --enable-languages=fortran,c,c++
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.3.0 (GCC)

And this is my mvn config

Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T22:59:23+05:30)
Maven home: /Users/vino/Downloads/apache-maven-3.2.5
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

I have a maven project where I have my .proto files and I try to create respective c++ files. There is no problem with the proto files or pom.xml (since its working fine with previous version of Mac OS X).

Now when I try to build the project (mvn clean install -P nar-packaging-type) i get the following error.

```
[INFO] Compiling 3 native files
[ERROR] /var/folders/vz/rzm109gn1cb7tpwr5zs4_mpw0000gn/T//ccfJP4vJ.s:8123:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
[ERROR] /var/folders/vz/rzm109gn1cb7tpwr5zs4_mpw0000gn/T//ccfJP4vJ.s:8125:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
[ERROR] /var/folders/vz/rzm109gn1cb7tpwr5zs4_mpw0000gn/T//ccfJP4vJ.s:11711:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
[ERROR] /var/folders/vz/rzm109gn1cb7tpwr5zs4_mpw0000gn/T//ccfJP4vJ.s:11713:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
[ERROR] /var/folders/vz/rzm109gn1cb7tpwr5zs4_mpw0000gn/T//ccfJP4vJ.s:41590:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
[ERROR] /var/folders/vz/rzm109gn1cb7tpwr5zs4_mpw0000gn/T//ccfJP4vJ.s:43291:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
[ERROR] /var/folders/vz/rzm109gn1cb7tpwr5zs4_mpw0000gn/T//ccfJP4vJ.s:43294:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
[ERROR] /var/folders/vz/rzm109gn1cb7tpwr5zs4_mpw0000gn/T//ccfJP4vJ.s:43744:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
[ERROR] /var/folders/vz/rzm109gn1cb7tpwr5zs4_mpw0000gn/T//ccfJP4vJ.s:43823:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
[ERROR] /var/folders/vz/rzm109gn1cb7tpwr5zs4_mpw0000gn/T//ccfJP4vJ.s:45369:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
[ERROR] /var/folders/vz/rzm109gn1cb7tpwr5zs4_mpw0000gn/T//ccfJP4vJ.s:45371:suffix or operands invalid for `movq'
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.054 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-15T16:46:38+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-nar-plugin:2.1-SNAPSHOT:nar-compile (default-nar-compile) on project gpbmessages: NAR: Compile failed: g++ failed with return code 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Am I missing any configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to build it with `--disable-asm` parameter.

Comment: I'm not able to add "--diable-asm" as a part of mvn command. Can you please tell me how exactly to use it ?